# ¿Cómo encontrar el valor mas alto y bajo en una columna con NAs?

Tags: rstudio

Tengo una base de datos, compuesta por fechas y temperaturas máximas de diferentes días, quiero encontrar la temperatura mas alta de la columna de temperatura
he intentado con ese código,pero cuando lo corro me muestra que hay N/A y no me aparece la cantidad

```
max(df$temperatura)
```

este es una muestra

```
2007    35.9
2007    37.4
2007    NA
2007    37.8
2007    39.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muchas funciones, como `max()` o `min()` son capaces de lidiar con valores `NA`, puedes usar el parámetro `na.rm=TRUE` para ignorar estos valores:

```
x <- c(20, 29, NA, 5)

max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 29

 min(x, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 5

> range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
[1]  5 29
```